# Laravel Mix vue not working and not found css

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

Here is my step.

php artisan ui vue
npm install
npm run dev

[app.blade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cYcS.jpg)

[webpack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZwBS.jpg)

i'm  sure the path js/app.js and css/app.css is correct.
but i still got [html front](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVggy.jpg),which step am i missing?

Comment: Can you confirm that webpack/mix is creating the files? Does your browser's DevTools (F12) point out that the css/js is not found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `asset()`

```php
<link href="{{ asset('css/main.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<script`` src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-asset